# How to query Groups and sort them in descending order based on number of users?

Tags: django

I need to create a query using the ORM that satisfies the following conditions:

- Exclude the groups that the current user belongs to
- Sorts the groups in descending order by the number of users

What I have tried so far is:

```
groups = (
    Group.objects.exclude(
        id__in=request.user.groups.all().values_list("id", flat=True)
    )
    .annotate(users=Count("user_set"))
    .order_by("-users")
)
```

This is excluding properly the groups that the current user belongs to, but I don't have so clear how I can achieve the ordering.

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'user_set' into field.

Comment: when you add the `get()` method right after you use order_by method, what do you get ? its like `.order_by("-users").get())`

Comment: @Lumenified, The same error _Cannot resolve keyword 'user_set' into field._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User's `groups` field has [`related_query_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) set as `user`. So try this:

```
Group.objects.exclude(
    id__in=request.user.groups.all().values_list("id", flat=True)
)
.annotate(users=Count("user"))
.order_by("-users")
```